# Prove by mathematical induction that the following inequality hold

Tags: analysis, induction

I tried to prove using mathematical induction the following inequality

$(1+\frac{3}{\sqrt{n}})^n>n$

I am not going to write the first two steps, just the third one for $n=k+1$, I got

$(1+\frac{3}{\sqrt{k+1}})^{k+1}>(1+\frac{3}{\sqrt{k+1}})^{k}(1+\frac{3}{\sqrt{k+1}})$

And everytime I find something that is smaller than the last result so I can not see how to use the second step from the induction, $(1+\frac{3}{\sqrt{k}})^{k}>k$,  to show the inequality.
I tried to use somehow Bernoulli inequality but i got nothing.

Thanks a lot, if you can give me just a little hint or instruction.

Comment: Do you have to use induction, or is this your chosen route through?

Comment: No, it is not mentioned that is by induction but I wanted to exercise the principle of mathematical induction, and tried to prove by induction.  I also thought about the binomial expansion.

Comment: Is it enough to show that $\frac{3k}{\sqrt{k+1}}> 1$ for all $k\geq 4$?

Comment: Suppose that you have two functions, $~f(n),~$ and $~g(n)~$ that were defined for all $~n \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ such that $~0 < f(n), g(n).~$  Further suppose that $~f(1) > g(1),~$ and you wanted to prove, by induction, that $~f(n) > g(n),~$ for all $~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}.~$  There are two standard approaches: [1] Show that in general, $~f(n+1) - f(n) > g(n+1) - g(n).~$ [2] Show that in general, $~\displaystyle \frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)} > \frac{g(n+1)}{g(n)}.~$